# Passing parameters from controller to javascript to rendered view in Ruby on Rails with jQuery and AJAX

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to Ajaxify a Ruby on Rails application to avoid the reloading of every page after a user interaction.

I now manage to have a new idea created behind the scenes but not to display it once it has been created.

Here is my code :

**form in the ideas views :**

```
<div id="new_proposition_form" style="display:none">
    <%= form_for(@new_proposition, :remote => true) do |f| %>
        <%= f.text_field :title, :class => "proposition_input", :id => "new_proposition_input"  %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :created_by %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :father_id %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :procontra %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :created_at %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

**create action in the ideas controller :**

```
  def create
    @idea = Idea.new(params[:idea])
    @idea.created_at = Time.now

    respond_to do |format|
      if @idea.save
        format.html { redirect_to play_path, :notice => 'Idea was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :json => @idea, :status => :created, :location => @idea }
        format.js 
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.json { render :json => @idea.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**create.js.erb in the ideas views :**

```
$("<%= escape_javascript render(:file => 'ideas/new_proposition.html.erb') %>").insertBefore('#end_of_propositions_list');
```

where "end_of_propositions_list" is the unique identifier of the displayed ideas list.

What I am struggling with is the following :

if the **new_proposition.html.erb** view in the ideas views is something like :

```
<div>
  New proposition added
</div>
```

with a code that is not referring to any object or variable it kind of works, i.e. the user can see a confirmation of what happened. Therefore I know that the remote action initiated in the browser hit the controller which hit the javascript template which hit a partial view.

Now I would like the newly created idea to appear instead, using a partial that retrieves its attributes and takes care of the formatting.
I feel I need to pass the id of the newly created idea from the create action in the ideas controller to the create.js script that is called by format.js and then to the partial so that it knows what idea to pull from the database.

I do not know how to handle this parameter passing from the create controller action to the create.js and to the partial view and would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks good to me...? So what you want to do next is pass the instance variable @idea from controller to the partial:

```
$("<%= escape_javascript render(
    :file => 'ideas/new_proposition.html.erb', 
    :idea => @idea) %>")
.insertBefore('#end_of_propositions_list');
```

and then access the @idea in your view:

```
<div>New proposition added</div>
<div>Title: <%= @idea.title => </div>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Things look so simple when they work... Many thanks, tw airbal, this is exactly what I needed. I accepted your answer but I unfortunately still have to wait for a few reputation points to upvote it...

Answer (score 0):

In the views rendered by that controller you can acces variables with an @, so in create.js you could acces to @idea.id directly

Comment: Thanks IBueno. And how can I then pass it from the create.js view to the partial new_proposition.html view ?

Comment: The partials rendered from a view have acces to the same variables as the principal view. Anyway when you render a partial you can pass variables to it using :locals, ill give you an example:

[code]<%= render :partial => 'my_partial',
           :locals => { :var => "some value"} %>
[/code]
Now inside the partial you can use var

Comment: I thought it was the case for .html.erb principal views only, not for .js.erb views. Thank you IBueno, this is helpful.